# JS regex to match two possible combinations

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to capture a certain combination of letters followed by a number (any amount), represented in a variable called `input`. The letters are strict, the numbers are not. The letters are either at the beginning of a string or followed immediately after a backslash.

So for example, I would need to non-case-sensitively capture:

- ab12345678google
- cd4321newyorkpost
- anything\here\ab1357
- something\too\cd2468

For these, I have a simple rule that works (well, two rules):

```
input.value.match(/^(ab|cd)[0-9]+/i) || input.value.match(/\\(ab|cd)[0-9]+/i)
```

However, it is also possible to a string called `test` to exist right before the set letters which I would also need to capture (either from the beginning or after a backslash again). So besides capturing just the given two letters, I would also need to capture these occurrences as well where the `test` before the letters is the strict factor, e.g.:

- testcd4321newyorkpost
- anything\here\testab1357

I'm quite sure it's possible to place an "optional" lookup of some sort in the match query without rewriting the rules for `test` separately, but as new as I am with regex I'm not sure what would I be looking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(?:^|\\)(?:test)?(?:ab|cd)\d+
```

Which is:

- Match start or `\`
- Match optional string `test`
- Match `ab` or `cd`
- Match 1+ digits

Comment: This is perfect! However it's missing the non-case-sensitivity, so `TEST` won't be captured?

Comment: I didn't include `/.../i` (just wanted to show full regex) You may use `/(?:^|\\)(?:test)?(?:ab|cd)\d+/i`

Comment: Very nice solution! +1

Comment: The regex works like a charm, but I cannot get the JS to work nor validate: `input.value.match(/(?:^|\\)(?:test)?(?:ab|cd)\d+/i)`

Comment: In JS console `/(?:^|\\)(?:test)?(?:ab|cd)\d+/i.test('testcd4321newyorkpost')` is returning `true`

Comment: My numbed eyes were missing a parentheses, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make the text `test` optional?

```
(?:test)?(ab|cd)[0-9]+
```

should work for any of your situations.